# Animating QWidget In destructor *NOT WORKING*

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on simple (QT) program in which I want to play an animation just before the object (***QWidget*** like ***QPushButton***) is deleted.

For this purpose I wrote all code for animation in object's deconstructor but the **QPropertyAnimation** is not doing it's work i.e, animation is not playing I don't know what happens.

```
AnimatedButton::~AnimatedButton() {
    qInfo() << "Called!";
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation((QObject*)this, "geometry",   this);
    animation->setDuration(5000);
    animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutExpo);
    QRect geometry = this->geometry();
    animation->setStartValue(geometry);
    geometry.setWidth(0);
    geometry.setHeight(0);
    animation->setEndValue(geometry);
    animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
    return;
}
```

Note that I see

```
Called!
```

in console

Comment: As soon as you exit the destructor, the animated button will be destroyed. I doubt you can have an animation running on it *afterwards*. Do you mean to delay destruction while the animation runs?

Comment: How do you delete the button?

Comment: When the destructor is called, it's already too late.  You'll need to do any animations you want to do *first*, and then delete the button only after the animations have completed.